# Display woocommerce product_cat child terms with thumbnails

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic, thumbnails, terms

I was wondering if someone could give me a hand. I would like to display the child categories of my woo commerce store categories along with the thumbnails I have set for them in my dashboard. I have set up two parent categories "Men" "Women". Under these two parents I have a few categories for each as children. From what I understand the woo commerce categories are formulated through a custom taxonomy. So I did not use `get_the_category()` instead I used `get_terms()`. I have used the code below, The thumbnails and the perma links work for each term but this code is still displaying the parent terms. Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here? I really appreciate the help!

```
<?php

    $taxonomyName = "product_cat";
    $prod_categories = get_terms($taxonomyName, array(
            'orderby'=> 'name',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'hide_empty' => 1
    ));  

    foreach( $prod_categories as $prod_cat ) :
            $terms = get_terms($taxonomyName, array('parent' => $prod_cat->term_id, 'orderby' => 'slug', 'hide_empty' => false));
            $cat_thumb_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $prod_cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
            $cat_thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $cat_thumb_id );
            $term_link = get_term_link( $prod_cat, 'product_cat' );
    ?>

    <li><a href="<?php echo $term_link; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $cat_thumb_url; ?>" alt="<?php echo $prod_cat->name; ?>" /></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: @PieterGoosen I have restructured the function and have given more information about the question. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure that you do actually need `get_terms()` twice. It looks very ineffecient and overboard. I don't know if you need this for ordering purposes, but still, there are better ways of doing this without hitting the db so hard. One alternative is to make one call to `get_terms()` and then use `usort()` to sort your terms by parent. But this is beyond what your question is about.

There are a couple of ways to exclude the parent terms

- Simply use the `exclude` parameter in `get_terms()` to exclude the parent categories. If your parents have id's 1 and 2, then you would add `'exclude' => [1, 2],` to your arguments in `get_terms()`· (*Note, the new short array syntax is only available from PHP 5.4. For older versions use `'exclude' => array( 1, 2 ),`*)
- You can also just loop over the parents. If your parents are top level terms, then their parent id will be `0`, so you can simply add the following in your `foreach` loop

  ```
  if ( $prod_cat->parent == 0 )
      continue;
  ```

  Alternatively, you can use their respective ids to skip them

  ```
  if ( $prod_cat->term_id == 1 || $prod_cat->term_id == 2 )
      continue;
  ```

Comment: My pleasure. Enjoy :-)